# Why use Euclidean distance in linear model?

Tags: statistics

The method of least squares is the most basic method in statistical linear models. For the simplest linear model$$Y_i=\beta_0+X_i\beta_1+\epsilon_i$$we are looking for $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ that minimizes the Euclidean distance $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|Y_i-\beta_0-X_i\beta_1|^2$. I learned statistics and an engineering student asked me why not use  $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|Y_i-\beta_0-X_i\beta_1|$ or things like $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|Y_i-\beta_0-X_i\beta_1|^4$, I got stuck...... Is there any convincing answer for this question?

Comment: Minimizing the $1$-norm of the residual is also a popular approach, and is more robust against outliers.  Minimizing the $2$-norm is nice because there's a closed form solution (you just have to solve the normal equations), and also gives you an optimal solution (in some sense) when the noise is Gaussian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most frequently given rationales is that if one assumes the errors are independent and distributed as $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then the least-squares estimators of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ coincide with the maximum-likelihood estimators.

Another rationale is the Gauss--Markov theorem.  In that theorem **it is not assumed that anything has a normal (or "Gaussian") distribution** and **it is not even assumed that the errors all have the same distribution**. The assumptions are

- The errors $\varepsilon_i$ have expected value $0$;
- The errors $\varepsilon_i$ all have the same (finite) variance, which let us denote $\sigma^2$;
- The errors $\varepsilon_i$ are uncorrelated (but not necessarily independent).

The **conclusion** is that the least-squares estimators $\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1$ are the "best linear unbiased estimators" of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$.  That means that among all linear unbiased estimators of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, they have the smallest mean squared error $\mathbb E\left(\left(\hat\beta_i - \beta_i\right)^2\right)$.

Let us be careful about what "linear" means.  (I know of an instance where someone said they were "affine" but not "linear"; that person was confused.)  **"Linear" means that the mapping**
$$
\begin{bmatrix} Y_1 \\  \vdots \\  Y_n\end{bmatrix} \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} \hat\beta_0 \\  \hat\beta_1 \end{bmatrix} \text{ (with $\begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\  \vdots \\  X_n\end{bmatrix}$ fixed)}
$$
**is linear,** i.e. it is additive and 1st-degree homogeneous.

The central idea of the proof is a lemma saying that the least-squares estimators are uncorrelated with every linear unbiased estimator of $0$.  A linear unbiased estimator of $0$ is a linear combination of $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ with coefficients that may depend on the (observable) $X$ values but not on unobservables such as $\beta_0,\beta_1,\sigma^2$, and whose expected value remains $0$ regardless of the values of those unobservables.

Another rationale is that least-squares is easy to work with.  For example, suppose you want a $90\%$ confidence interval for $\beta_1$.  You get (assuming normality and independence) something based on a $t$-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom, and making use of $\hat\beta_1$ and $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ (the dependence on the $X$s is non-linear, and the non-linearity can be isolated in the inversion of a $2\times 2$ matrix that depends on the $X$s).  The hypothesis test corresponding to that confidence interval can be shown to be precisely the likelihood-ratio test.